# crystal reports error in formula

Tags: crystal-reports, if-statement

so, i'm trying to generate a IF Then in crystal reports, basic syntax (i will use crystal syntax if that's what you give me). i have a value coming back from a stored procedure ranging from 0 to 4. depending on that number, i want to return back different phrases.

right now what i got:

```
formula = ""  
IF {sp_cr_getSubsequentVisitBySubVisitID;1.Judgement} = 1 THEN   
    formula = "poor"  
end if
```

if i change the ' 1 ' to ' true ', it'll save it, but it comes up with an error if i use ' 1 ' or ' "1" '. I've also tried using == and 1 = {sp_cr....}

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal syntax, and Basic syntax AFAICT, require that you declare the variable to which you would like to assign a value. This is a tested example (my test field returns int as well):

```
stringVar formula := "";
if {sp_cr_getSubsequentVisitBySubVisitID;1.Judgement} = 1 then 
  formula := "completed" 
else 
  formula := "n/a"
```

PS: don't forget the semicolon after the variable declaration.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. Tried this and it still wouldn't save without error. Upon further investigation I found that the formula field is expecting that 1 to be a boolean and not numeric. How do I fix this? I've verified the database on a visit that returns 4 for this value, and even tried creating a new formula field after that, still wants a boolean.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I tested this and it works for me; so this is something I would probably need to see in the flesh to understand. At any rate: good luck to you!

Comment: after fooling around a bit longer, did a reboot just to clear out any memory that Crystal Reports may have developed and now your solution magically works. Thanks for the help Adam!